# How to save a record that belongs to a User in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this little Laravel application that allows Users to post a project. Currently I'm trying to assign the posted project to the particular user who posted it. I have defined the Eloquent relationships nicely also I have defined the Foreign key in the projects migration. However, when I try to post a project I get this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null`.

This is the method that handles the posting of project.

```
public function storeProject(User $user)
    {
        $this->validate();

        $fileName = $this->files->store('uploads');

        $user->projects()->create([
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'files' => $fileName,
            'skills' => $this->skills,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ]);

        session()->flash('message', 'Your Project has been posted Successfully!');
        $this->reset();
    }
```

This is my migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('files');
            $table->string('skills');
            $table->foreignIdFor(User::class);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: The error message suggests that the value of `$user->id` is `null`. Have you done some debugging of `$user` and `$user->id` to confirm it has the expected value?

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to make foreign keys for migrations.

You can try to do it this way:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
```

You should also check that in your Models/Project.php the *user_id* attribute is specified in the fillable array.

Since it is possible that not being specified in the fillable array it is omitting the value when creating a new one.

Comment: Just tried this, same error.

Comment: This is my fillable Sir, `protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'files', 'skills', 'user_id'];`